# insert a password into excel workbook using python \ C#

Tags: c#, python, excel, passwords

for all the python \ C# developers:

have you ever managed to insert a password into excel workbook, using python \ C#?

couldn't find any solution using python. only using VBA, which worked just fine, but the job requires python/c#...

thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a solution, you can use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` to open an excel file and add an password to it.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

//create your spreadsheet here...
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
wb.Password = password;
wb.SaveAs("spreadsheet.xls")
```

Comment: this is using C# right? and how do i "catch" the WorkbookObject? thank you so much...

Comment: Yes this is C#.

Comment: You don't catch WorkbookObject, you create it.

Comment: but i already created it. i want to add a password to an existing workbbok,,,

Comment: thank you. but i get red line under the "Application excel = new Application();"

Comment: solution: i needed to declare: private static Excel.Workbook MyBook = null; 
private static Excel.Application MyApp = null;